# How to find the function symbol in nm or objdump when using shared_ptr for abstract class?

Tags: c++, compilation, debug-symbols, objdump, nm

I use shared_ptr for an abstract class ABC. ABCImpl class is the implementation of ABC. abc_ptr is a shared_ptr< ABC> points to an ABCImpl objects. In caller function, abc_ptr will call one of the member function (func_in_ABC) in ABC class. The compile is successful. But when I use nm or objdump, I could only see the symbol for abc_ptr. There is no symbol displayed for func_in_ABC() in the caller function.

Anyone knows why, or how an I get the output for the symbol for func_in_ABC() in the caller function?

The code is as follows:
In ABC.h:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class ABC
{
    public:
        virtual void func_in_ABC(const int param) = 0;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<ABC> ABCPtr;
ABCPtr get_ABC_ptr();
```

In ABCImpl.h:

```
#include "ABC.h"

class ABCImpl : public 
{
    public:
        ABCImpl() {}
        void func_in_ABC(const int param);
    private:
        int data;
};
```

In ABCImpl.cpp:

```
#include "ABCImpl.h"

ABCPtr get_ABC_ptr()
{
        return ABCPtr(new ABCImpl());
}

void ABCImpl::func_in_ABC(const int param)
{
    data = param;
}
```

In caller function D.cpp:

```
#include "D.h"
#include "ABC.h"

void D::call_ABC()
{
    ABCPtr abc_ptr = get_ABC_ptr();
    abc_ptr->func_in_ABC(100);
}
```

The output for D.o from nm:

```
         U _Unwind_Resume
         U get_ABC_ptr()
0000000000000000 T D::call_ABC()
0000000000000000 W boost::shared_ptr<ABC>::operator->() const
0000000000000000 r boost::shared_ptr<ABC>::operator->() const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
         U __assert_fail
         U __gxx_personality_v0
```

If I change the definition of func_in_ABC in ABC.h, the compilation for D.cpp will fail. I think it will check the definition of class ABC when compiling D.o. But why I can't find the symbol at caller to map to the definition in ABC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `func_in_ABC` is a virtual function, you don't actually need the symbol name to call it. You just need the offset into the virtual table for that specific virtual function.

If you make `func_in_ABC` non-virtual, you should see the symbol show up in the `nm` output.

Comment: how can I get the offset of the virtual table for that function? And how can I map the offset to the func_in_ABC in ABC or ABCImpl?

Comment: @Jimmy : you don't need to. The compiler handles that for you. It would probably be worthwhile to read up on [what the difference is between how virtual and non-virtual member functions are called](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.3).

Comment: Thank you. I know that compiler will handle that. But I want to know any way to get the offset to let me know the pointer of v-table maps the func_in_ABC, just like compiler. Or any command I can get the pointer/offset information? I don't need to make a compiler, but I want to know the dependency / linking information from the compiled object.

Comment: @Jimmy : you can't statically analyze an object file to figure out its dynamic dependencies (virtual function calls are dynamically "linked"), simply because that information is not available. Furthermore, as far as I know the used vtable offsets aren't exposed by the compiler (except through the generated code).